# qr-code reader for windows

Tags: windows, qr-code

i'm looking for a program which runs on windows and can read/decode qr-codes.

at this state i'm happy for every suggestion, but the more requirements it hits the better:

- must run on windows
- must decode qr-codes
- should be gratis and even better free ([FOSS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_and_open-source_software))
- should read qr-codes from webcam
- should read qr-codes from files (png, jpg, pdf, etc.) - the more formats the better.
- may read qr-codes directly from screen
- may read qr-codes directly from other sources like scanners, etc.
- may decode other 1d- & 2d-codes

---

as a pendant on linux i use [QtQR](https://launchpad.net/qr-tools) which fulfills at least the "musts" & "shoulds" beside creating qr-codes (which isn't necessary in this case).

Answer (score 2):

I recommend [Sharex](https://getsharex.com/). It's free & open source.

It can:

- Run on windows / steam
- Reads qr-codes from image files
- Reads qr-codes from screen

And so many features that I find it very useful:

- Screen capture region
- Screen recording (video / gif)
- Easy upload captured image to image sharing (e.g imgur)
- Color Picker
- Ruler
- And many other features that I haven't tried

Comment: although it is a bit of a overshoot for just decoding qr-codes (hence not really user-/noob-friendly), it seems to be the best recommendation so far.

Comment: No-go for me since it lacks webcam QR code scanning...

Answer (score 0):

there is one program i found [*CodeTwo QR Code Desktop Reader & Generator*](https://www.codetwo.com/freeware/qr-code-desktop-reader/):

- runs on Windows XP SP3 and up
- reads qr-codes
- is only gratis but **not free** (FOSS) - but anyhow seems to be also free for commercial use
- reads qr-codes from webcam
- reads qr-codes from files
- reads qr-codes from screen
- additionally it can also create qr-codes

for now i have no idea how good, safe and privacy friendly it is, since i haven't used it... but it is the only thing i found! :-(
--> hence comments/experiences about this one are also highly appreciated!

Comment: Did you wind up using this tool at all?  If so, can you update your answer with your experiences?

Comment: @RockPaperLizard i usually use FOSS! so i hardly use Windows and Windows-only-tools, but it worked and also the few Windows users who asked me for a QR-decoder didn't complain about anything... i would say it does its job but unfortunately i have no solid long time experience to share.

Comment: No-go for me since it can't read QR codes generated by Brave...

Comment: @Redoman: why that?!?

Comment: @DJCrashdummy no idea, it probably does not support the format.

Comment: @Redoman QR codes are more or less an international standard... so if it is a QR code, it should be readable; perhaps it only shows some text (if the data type isn't "supported" for some "instant/quick actions"), but it should still be readable.

Comment: BTW: every now and then i noticed some readers have a hard time reading the QR code, if there is no resp. a too small border around the code.

Comment: @DJCrashdummy there are many different ways to encode data in a QR code. If the reading software has not implement a specific format, then it cannot read it. Another evidence of CodeTwo being the problem, is that other readers I tried can read it without any problem.

Comment: CodeTwo QR Code Desktop Reader and Generator runs on Windows –– is there any similar software for Mac? https://www.codetwo.com/freeware/qr-code-desktop-reader/

Answer (score 0):

If FOSS is essential, I would go for Zbar (http://zbar.sourceforge.net/)

The GUI can apparently look at video streams as well as files, and seems nicely extensible. It says it's currently unstable but I've honestly had no issues, and there's no dependency hell with it that I can see.

Beside QR Codes it can also decode EAN-13/UPC-A, UPC-E, EAN-8, Code 128, Code 39 and Interleaved 2 of 5.

Comment: well... i'd say FOSS is preferred, not essential because of lacking alternatives! **||** i also stumbled across this project, but i don't see any GUI and sadly it also refused to work with my webcam. :-( **--** citation from the windows-readme: `This version of the package includes *only command line programs*. (The graphical interface is scheduled for a future release)` **||** but thanks for the answer anyway!

Comment: appears to be now offline...

Comment: It's still around, just not updated, try http://zbar.sourceforge.net/download.html

Comment: The copyright date is 2010, and the homepage was last modified in 2011, so this app appears to be no longer supported. https://zbar.sourceforge.net/